# Convert to postscript format using the Backend command before sending to a printer

Tags: pdf, cups, postscript

Without using CUPS is there an way to add something on the Backend line in the print queue to convert all print sent to a queue to postscript from PDF format before sending the output to the printer?

Comment: What's wrong with invoking `pdftops`?

Comment: I have been tring to do this but without success. So exactly how would you include pdftops in the Backend line? Can you show me what that would look like in an example. I can't seem to find the correct syntax for this. I have done a lot of UNIX scripting but printer configuration is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly to do this depends a lot on your print spool setup, CUPS is one of many options here.
(Yes, printing in Unix is somewhat of a black art).